# C++ function not returning properly: string destructor being called

Tags: c++

I have asked this question elsewhere and gotten a vague answer, and I think it is because I am not understanding how to use the `new` keyword.

The project I am working on is just something to give help me begin learning C++, but I am coming from a knowledge in Java. It is just a collection of structs and functions that I will eventually use in a text-based game.

The function I am having trouble with is `getStats()`, which will return some values of variables of structure wood and the structure from which it inherits.

```
/**
*Returns information regarding the status of the wood.
*@param the wood to retrieve.
*@return A string representing the stats.
*/
string getStats(wood toGet)
{
    string toReturn;

    //Substruct specific variables.
    toReturn += "Type: ";
    toReturn += toGet.type;
    toReturn += "\nAge: ";
    toReturn += toGet.age;

    //Superstruct variables.
    toReturn += "\nHeight: ";
    toReturn += toGet.height;
    toReturn += "\nWidth: ";
    toReturn += toGet.width;
    toReturn += "\nWeight: ";
    toReturn += toGet.weight;
    toReturn += "\nGeneric name: ";
    toReturn += toGet.name;
    toReturn += "\nState of Matter: ";
    toReturn += toGet.stateOfMatter;
    toReturn += "\nFlammable: ";
    toReturn += toGet.flammable;
    toReturn += "\n";

    return toReturn;
}
```

I realize that I am doing this in a silly way right now, I will rework it with an array and a loop, but for now I am using this method. On the other website I asked it on they informed me to use `new`, but when I do so like this:

```
string toReturn = new string;
```

it gives me an error:

> conversion from `‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string *}’` to non-scalar type `‘std::string {aka std::basic_string }’` requested

The full source is here: http://pastebin.com/UawrwYj7

The output from a sample run is below.

> Type: Birch
>   Age:
>   Height:
>   Width:
>   Weight: d
>   Generic name:
>   State of Matter: solid
>   Flammable:

Comment: The best way to use `new` in C++ is not at all. The language doesn't work like that.

Comment: note: you probably want `string getStats()` (it's OO..). btw what's the problem with your original code? why do you want to use `new`?

Comment: The code you have looks perfectly useful; there is **absolutely no need to use `new`**. Is this code working correctly for you?

Comment: Your original code is certainly not perfect (it's very inefficient to concatenate strings like that), but it's correct and exception-safe C++. Those who suggested to use `new` are wrong.

Comment: Have you ever considered using a `std::ostringstream`?

Comment: I can't see where you're instantiating a new string anywhere in your code.

Comment: Some comments regarding your full code, unrelated to this one: 1. Since `item` is used as a base class, it should either have a public virtual destructor or a protected nonvirtual destructor. 2. In `item`'s and `wood`'s constructors, prefer initialization over assignment. 3. Prefer passing objects of class type like `wood` and `string` by lvalue reference to const instead of by value.

Comment: @Robᵩ: No, but I found that the problem had nothing to do with string as my previous source had told. It was instead caused by using += on a string when I was using doubles.

Comment: "I have asked this question elsewhere and gotten a vague answer" - that might be because it's a vague question.  I'm not even sure what the problem you're asking about is (and based on the above comment about "using doubles", the question as posted doesn't even discuss the problem you're having).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Right -- the question is actually "Why doesn't Age, Height or Weight show up in the output?"

Answer (score 4):

1) You don't need `new`. C++ isn't Java. In C++ objects spring into existence when they are declared.

2) The expression `w.getStats(w)` is redundant. You don't need to pass `w` as a parameter, it is implicitly passed as the `this` pointer.

3) You can't do this:

```
double x;
toReturn += x;
```

There is no `std::string operator+= (double)`.  Prior to the most recent version of the C++ standard, formatting was not generally done by the `std::string` class. If you have a recent enough compiler, you can replace your `height`, `width`, `weight`, etc, code with:

```
double x;
toReturn += std::to_string(x);
```

I would recommend, however, that you use the operator `<<`. This will allow you to format strings or send your data to a file, according to how you use it.

Here is your updated `getStats`:

```
// Untested code
std::string getStats()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "Type: " << this->type << "\n";
    oss << "Age: " << this->age << "\n";
    oss << "Height: " << this->height << "\n";
    oss << "Width: " << this->width << "\n";
    // and so on
    return oss.str();
}
```

Later, when you learn how to override `operator<<`, try this instead:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const wood& w) {
  os << "Type: " << w.type << "\n";
  os << "Age: " << w.age << "\n";
  os << "Height: " << w.height << "\n";
  os << "Width: " << w.width << "\n";
  // and so on
  return os;
}
std::string getStats() {
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << *this;
  return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: Formatting *is* provided by the `<string>` library, though: `toReturn += std::to_string(x);`.

Comment: I think you mean `ostringstream`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, of course. That's C++11-specific, isn't it? I'll update my answer in minute.

Comment: @aschepler - Yes, you are right. I caught that before I read your comment. It's updated now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When the original version will be called, the string will be first constructed, filled, then a copy will be returned and original string (that is on `getStats()`'s stack) will be destroyed.

`new string;` returns a *pointer* to a string, not string object, so the variable to hold it must be pointer - `string *`, not `string`. This, however, involves dynamic memory management - and you do not want it in this case.

Summary: to do anything in C++, get some decent book and learn at least the basics, as C++ is really different from Java.

**Edit**: also, to make your function work nicely, go read about [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).